# Javascript length always displays 1. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, match

I have the following Javascript which is part of a larger function. I am doing a javascript match then trying to get the length of the match. The problem is, the length always returns 1 even when it is 10 characters long.

```
var content = $(this).text();
var word = /#(\w+)/ig;
var query = content.match(word);

alert(query + ' | ' + query.length);
```

How can I get the accurate value for the length of the match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the result of `String.match` with a global regex is an array. `query.length` tells you there is only one match; you can access the matched string with `query[0]`.

It appears to be a string in your `alert` call because `Array.toString` is equivalent to `array.join(',')`. With just one element, it shows that single element.